# When I click the sum, multiply and divide button I got "NaN" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
Here is my code:
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script>

var a,b,result;

function setValues()
{
a = Number(document.getElementById("a").Value);
b = Number(document.getElementById("b").Value);
}

function sum()
{
setValues();
result = a+b;
alert("The Sum For The Values Is "+result);
}

function multiply()
{
setValues();
result = a*b;
alert("The Product For The Values Is "+result);
}

function div()
{
setValues();
result = a/b;
alert("The Quotient For The Values Is "+result);
}

</script>

</HEAD>


<STYLE>
body
{
background-color: #b0c4de;
}

 </STYLE>

 <body>
 <CENTER>
 <H1><B><U> Fun Facts!</B></U></H1>
 <H4>Did You Know There Are Over 7 Billion People In The World!!!</H4>
 <div>
 <input Id="a" Type="Text"/>
 <input Id="b" Type="Text"/>
 <input Type="Button"  onclick="sum()" Value="sum"/>
 <input Type="Button"  onclick="multiply()" Value="multiply"/>
 <input Type="Button"  onclick="div()" Value="divide"/>
 </div>
 </body>



 </CENTER>






</HTML>
```

This is a simple calculator, but when i clicks um,multiply or divide, I get the "NaN          error. I add the alert system, so the answer is the sum,product, or quotient and then the answer, but i DO GET THE ALERT SYSTEM, BUT THE RESULT i GET IS NaN
     Please help.
     thanks

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <script>

    var a,b,result;

    function setValues()
    {
    a = Number(document.getElementById("a").Value);
    b = Number(document.getElementById("b").Value);
    }

    function sum()
    {
    setValues();
    result = a+b;
    alert("The Sum For The Values Is "+result);
    }
 
    function multiply()
    {
    setValues();
    result = a*b;
    alert("The Product For The Values Is "+result);
    }

    function div()
    {
    setValues();
    result = a/b;
    alert("The Quotient For The Values Is "+result);
    }

    </script>

    </HEAD>


    <STYLE>
    body
    {
    background-color: #b0c4de;
    }

     </STYLE>

     <body>
     <CENTER>
     <H1><B><U> Fun Facts!</B></U></H1>
     <H4>Did You Know There Are Over 7 Billion People In The World!!!</H4>
     <div>
     <input Id="a" Type="Text"/>
     <input Id="b" Type="Text"/>
     <input Type="Button"  onclick="sum()" Value="sum"/>
     <input Type="Button"  onclick="multiply()" Value="multiply"/>
     <input Type="Button"  onclick="div()" Value="divide"/>
     </div>
     </body>



     </CENTER>






    </HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an simple mistake:

```
function setValues()
{
a = Number(document.getElementById("a").Value);
b = Number(document.getElementById("b").Value);
}
```

The `.Value` should be `.value` ...

Greetings from Austria

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayurRahul/h4g6gzf7/)